# Event Handling now confusing by listener

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, event-handling

I thought I had a good understanding of event handling until now that am reading this [Routed Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28VS.85%29.aspx) where **Event Listener** is mentioned

Here is my understanding

```
<!-- Sources -->
<Button x:Name="aButton" Click="MyHandler" />
or
<asp:Button ID="aButton" OnClick="MyHanlder" />

//handler
protected void MyHanlder(object source, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

From the documentation there is this statement under **what is a Routed Event** section

> The event can invoke **handlers** on **listeners** at the element tree root, and then route to 
>   successive child elements along the tree node route towards the node element that is the **event source**

From the code I showed above I know these  (Please correct me if am wrong):

- The *EventHandler* is `MyHanlder(....)`
- The *Event Source* is `aButton`

The question is I could not understand what is the *Event Listener* here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event listener is just another name for the the event handler.

From the point of view object with the handler it has a handler.
(This object implements a handler.)

From the point of view of the object which is calling the listener it is a listener.
(This object invokes a listener.)

They are the same thing.

Comment: this is still vague. Please can you throw more light

Comment: How is "they mean the same thing" vague?

Comment: From my point of view I posted an answer, from your point of view I posted a response.  Who the actor is can have an influence of what word you use.   An answer and a response is the same thing when you pose a question.

Comment: Appreciate your effort. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Event listner is an element in your layout, as it stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx

> Routed event listeners and routed event sources do not need to share a
>   common event in their hierarchy. Any UIElement or ContentElement can
>   be an event listener for any routed event. Therefore, you can use the
>   full set of routed events available throughout the working API set as
>   a conceptual "interface" whereby disparate elements in the application
>   can exchange event information. This "interface" concept for routed
>   events is particularly applicable for input events.